# Error in using Python Input Function in latest version

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I use the latest version of Python 3.6.1

I use the `input()` function in my script

```
F:\MyPython> type new.py
input_variable = input("Enter your name: ")
print ("your name is" + input_variable)
```

and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\MyPython\new.py", line 1, in <module>
    input_variable = input("Enter your name: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'xyz' is not defined
```

But when I use `raw_input()` I get the correct output.

Why do I get an error for `input()` even after installing the latest version?

Comment: You are calling xyz without defining it or assigning any value to it. Can you show the code you have written.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Python 3.6.1?

Comment: Yes it is 3.6.1

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: input_variable = input("Enter your name: ")
print ("your name is" + input_variable)

Comment: Inlined the code the OP posted in a comment, tidying.

Comment: [`raw_input` doesn't exist in python 3.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) You're using 2.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error
`x = input("")` takes only integers as input.

`x = raw_input("")` is for string
you might be trying to input 'string' using input() method.

Comment: That is not correct. `x = input("") does take string as input at least in Python 3.6.1

Comment: IMO, this is true for python 2, but not python 3.